# My MySQL SELECT query is returning all the rows in the table

Tags: mysql, select, left-join

I'm having trouble with this query. I want to `SELECT` one project from the `projects` table and all of the files associated with it from the `projects` table. Here's my query:

```
SELECT
    `projects`.`id` AS `project_id`,
    `projects`.`password` AS `project_password`,
    `projects`.`title` AS `project_title`,
    `projects`.`description` AS `project_description`,
    `projects`.`active` AS `project_active`,
    `files`.`file` AS `file_file`,
    `files`.`title` AS `file_title`,
    `files`.`category` AS `file_category`
FROM `projects`
LEFT JOIN `files` ON
    `projects`.`id` = "test_project3" AND
    `files`.`project_id` = "test_project3"
;
```

I was expecting the results to be a set with the columns `project_id`, `project_password`, `project_title`, `project_description`, `project_active`, `file_file`, `file_title`, and `file_category` (with the first two fields being the same data for every row returned and the rest varying per file).

Instead of just retrieving the project information and files for `test_project3`, this is apparently returning every project in the `projects` table.

Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd rather use `FROM projects
LEFT JOIN files ON
    projects.id = files.project_id WHERE projects.id = "test_project3"`

Comment: Good to know, I didn't know that that syntax worked, but thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to fix this is to move the predicate on `projects` table to the `WHERE` clause, and reference the join column rather than a constant in the ON clause.

Something like this:

```
  FROM `projects`
  LEFT
  JOIN `files`
    ON files.project_id = projects.id
 WHERE projects.id = 'test_project3'
```

(That's the normative pattern, and the pattern you would want to use if you were returning more than one row from projects.)

Comment: I think I was trying to put the `WHERE` clause before `LEFT JOIN` and I just assumed since that was a syntax error that I couldn't use a `WHERE` clause in a `JOIN` statement for some reason. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just use an `inner join` instead of a `left join`:

```
SELECT
    `projects`.`id` AS `project_id`,
    `projects`.`password` AS `project_password`,
    `projects`.`title` AS `project_title`,
    `projects`.`description` AS `project_description`,
    `projects`.`active` AS `project_active`,
    `files`.`file` AS `file_file`,
    `files`.`title` AS `file_title`,
    `files`.`category` AS `file_category`
FROM `projects`
INNER JOIN `files` ON
    `projects`.`id` = "test_project3" AND
    `files`.`project_id` = "test_project3"
;
```

The `left join` keeps all the rows in the `projects` table, regardless of whether or not there is a match in the `files` table.  You want to use the `join` as a filter, which is what an `inner join` does.

Comment: Yes, I want to return the correct project regardless of whether or not it has any files associated with it.